# A complex ragged hierarchy and generic queries in MDX with compound keys

Tags: ssas, mdx

Dimension is made with collection of key column attributes so:

```
...   
hierarchylevel2key = level2attribute + level1attribute
hierarchylevel1key = level1attribute
...
```

Hierarchy has many levels, so in the lowest levels of the hierarchy, the key combinations are quite complex:

```
[Dim].[Hierarchy].[level1].&[level2]&[level3]&[level4]&[level5]&[level6]&[level7]
```

Now if i want to make a generic named set for level5 members, it's in MDX:

```
[Dimension].[Hierarchy].[level5].members.item(2)
```

and it returns the second member of the level5, but because the **hierarchy is ragged (?)** sometimes this item(2) does not exist.

.

Do i have to make gazillion of different named sets and manually have to pick the right existing items for the sets?

Or alternatively have i made mistake building the dimension hierarchy this way ?